# Model generation for legacy tables

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

https://www.ruby-toolbox.com/projects/magic_model_generator We are unable to use the above gem, is there anything else which will fit the needs of generating schema / model classes from an existing legacy database for Rails3.

Comment: What's the problem with this one?

Comment: Doesn't work on Rails3, seems to work on Rails2 and it hasn't been maintained / updated for the last 5yrs

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only other gem for this is [Dr Nic's Magic Models](http://magicmodels.rubyforge.org/), but is suffers from the same problem as your suggestion, not updated for Rails 3.

I investigated this recently and came to the conclusion that you could either update Dr Nic´s gem to work with Rails 3 (and I would cheer you on if you did) or go for a table by table approach and model the legacy tables by hand.

Since I only had a small number of tables I choose to do it by hand. But getting Dr Nic's gem up to speed would be awesome so if you go that route let me know and maybe we could help out.